# Refactor multiple if-else

Tags: java

I have below code with lot of if else codition. Due to this if else code looking more complex and also sonar saying `"Refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 17 to the 15 allowed."`

Is there any other way so that I can reduce the complexcity.

```
    if (CONDITION1) {
        validatorVO.setErrorCode("ERROR_CODE_1");
    } else if (CONDITION2) {
        validatorVO.setErrorCode("ERROR_CODE_2");
    } else if (CONDITION3) {
        validatorVO.setErrorCode("ERROR_CODE_3");
    } else if (CONDITION4) {
        if (CONDITION5) {
            validatorVO.setErrorCode("ERROR_CODE_4");
        } else if (CONDITION6) {
            validatorVO.setErrorCode("ERROR_CODE_5");
        } else if (CONDITION7) {
            validatorVO.setErrorCode("ERROR_CODE_6");
        } else {
            validatorVO.setErrorCode("ERROR_CODE_7");
        }
    } else if (CONDITION8) {
        validatorVO.setErrorCode("ERROR_CODE_8");
    } else if (CONDITION9) {
        validatorVO.setErrorCode("ERROR_CODE_9");
    } else if (CONDITION10) {
        validatorVO.setErrorCode("ERROR_CODE_10");
    } else if (CONDITION11) {
        validatorVO.setErrorCode("ERROR_CODE_11");
    }
}
```

Note : Based on the condition error code will be different

Comment: All conditions are producing same result? Set errorCode to FAILED?

Comment: I don't think there is much to say without knowing the actual conditioning and context of the code.

Comment: Can you combine multiple conditions that have the same result with a logical or?

Comment: Does even your `else` statment returns the same result of your `ifs` statments ?

Comment: The nested `if` for CONDITION4 always does the same thing so you can remove all the nested conditions.

Comment: a switch statement can help as well.

Comment: You *could* combine different branches with OR logic if your only goal is to reduce cognitive complexity and get rid of the warning. However, before you do that, I would seriously consider adding some details to those error messages first. That way it will be easier to see which conditions can really be combined.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I agree, something which would help the person diagnosing the problem to solve it needs much more detail.

Comment: Try to reduce the number of `validatorVO.setErrorCode()` calls. Try setting result to a single `String`. Of course it will another `if` check at the end.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With your amended question, one option would be to maintain a `LinkedHashMap<Supplier<Boolean>, String>` with the error codes (to preserve order). Note that the order matters (if you put `CONDITION4` first, the combined conditions will never be checked).

```
Map<Supplier<Boolean>, String> conditions = new LinkedHashMap<> ();
conditions.put(() -> CONDITION1, "ERROR_CODE_1");
conditions.put(() -> CONDITION2, "ERROR_CODE_2");
conditions.put(() -> CONDITION3, "ERROR_CODE_3");
conditions.put(() -> CONDITION4 && CONDITION5, "ERROR_CODE_4");
conditions.put(() -> CONDITION4 && CONDITION6, "ERROR_CODE_5");
conditions.put(() -> CONDITION4 && CONDITION7, "ERROR_CODE_6");
conditions.put(() -> CONDITION4, "ERROR_CODE_7");
conditions.put(() -> CONDITION8, "ERROR_CODE_8");
conditions.put(() -> CONDITION9, "ERROR_CODE_9");
conditions.put(() -> CONDITION10, "ERROR_CODE_10");
conditions.put(() -> CONDITION11, "ERROR_CODE_11");
```

Then iterate:

```
for (Entry<Supplier<Boolean>, String> e : conditions.entrySet()) {
  if (e.getKey().get()) {
    validatorVO.setErrorCode(e.getValue());
    break;
  }
}
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**

Without knowing what the conditions are, it's hard to refactor the code too much.

You can write:

```
if (CONDITION1 || CONDITION2 || ... CONDITION11) validatorVO.setErrorCode("FAILED");
```

Of you may put the conditions in an array:

```
boolean[] conditions = {CONDITION1, CONDITION2, ...}
for (boolean b : conditions) {
  if (b) validatorVO.setErrorCode("FAILED");
}
```

Also note that you can exclude CONDITION5, CONDITION6 and CONDITION7 since they are ignored in your code (whether they are true or not makes not difference).

Comment: `CONDITION4` does have nested subconditions (not that they amount to much ;) ).

Comment: I have modified my question. Based on the condition error code will be different.

Comment: Condition are very different each other so can't combine

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty It's best to put all the information in your question from the beginning. See my update.

Comment: New answer is nice but I see only one issue with that. If condition 2 is dependent on condition 1 then it will won't work properly. For example if condition 1 means a == null then will display errror message. If condition 2 means a.getid()  so it will throw null pointer exception

Comment: Since iterating over the map entries should be ordered by insertion, you might want to use a `LinkedHashMap`. (CONDITION4 should not come before CONDITION4 && CONDITION5). `HashMap` does not guarantee order.

Comment: @assylias Map contains unique key. So if multiple condition is true then we will get only single value

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty Yes I was too quick on this one. See edit, which addresses your two comments.

Comment: @assylias Thanx for your answer its help a lot. Can you please help with one more thing. Why Supplier<Boolean> support duplicate key? Can you please explain on that

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty `Supplier` doesn't override `equals` or `hashcode`, so each new Supplier is unique from the Map's perpsective.

Answer (score 1):

If the same result, then you can do something like:

```
if (CONDITION1 || CONDITION2 ||CONDITION3
     || CONDITION4
     || CONDITION8 || CONDITION9 ||CONDITION10 || CONDITION11) {
        validatorVO.setErrorCode("FAILED");
}
```

Actually, your `CONDITION4` always evaluate

```
validatorVO.setErrorCode("FAILED");
```

regardless of `CONDITION5`, `CONDITION6`, `CONDITION7`(thanks to Peter Lawrey for the hint)

Comment: Note that should be `&& (CONDITION5 || CONDITION6 ||CONDITION7 || true)` ;)